# Setting up JIRA with multiple projects

Tags: jira

HI i need some advice on how to set up JIRA for our team.
We have multiple Projects that have multiple items that will need to be released on their own. For example if we have project A it will have 6 items that will be developed but each item needs to be released individually. Then there can be other projects with items that also need to be released individually.

If I want to use Bamboo to release the items and create the release notes etc what is the best way to set up JIRA?

Is it possible if I used 1 project but used components with 1 item to release just 1 component?

what other options do i have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Releases in JIRA are driven by `Versions` which belong to a project. This means that you can manage multiple releasable 'components' from a single project.

So for example, you could have the following versions;

- COMPONENT_A-1.0
- COMPONENT_A-2.0
- COMPONENT_B-1.0
- COMPONENT_B-2.0

Then when you allocate issues, select one of these as the fix version. When you generate release notes, or trigger a release in Bamboo you would use one of these versions for the release and it will track the issues that were assigned to it.

You can additionally use JIRA `Components` to pre-allocate issues to certain components if you don't like the idea of assigning them to a specific version in advance. There isn't however any way to add validation to enforce that issues from specific `Components` can only be allocated to certain `Versions`.

Note, there is also a JIRA plug-in available that adds support of component-based versioning; https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.deniz.jira.versioning

Comment: This sounds exactly what i need i just need to figure out how i set this up. i.e. how to add the versions you mention by component